# How to skip transaction in ActiveRecord for INSERT ONLY statement?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

Look at this example:

```
2.1.3 :001 > Stat.create!
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO `stats` (`created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('2015-03-16 11:20:08', '2015-03-16 11:20:08')
   (0.4ms)  COMMIT
 => #<Stat id: 1, uid: nil, country: nil, city: nil, created_at: "2015-03-16 11:20:08", updated_at: "2015-03-16 11:20:08">
```

As you can see the `create!` method execute insert statement inside useless transaction. How to disable transation in this case only (without disabling them in whole application)?

Comment: # Remove transactions
ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::MysqlAdapter.class_eval do
  def begin_db_transaction
  end

  def commit_db_transaction
  end
end

Comment: I might be missing a point here somewhere, but what's the problem with it being a transaction?

Comment: @Kanti Your solution will disable transactions in **whole** application.

Comment: @Almaron INSERT is atomic operation.

Comment: @maxd don't see a problem there.

Comment: @maxd - As Almaron has implied, you aren't saving all that much by skipping the transaction (2 DB roundtrips to start and commit the transaction).  The only case I can see this being an issue would be for very large quantities of INSERTs over a very brief period, at which point it's likely that ActiveRecord isn't the right tool for this.  That said, it can be done - see below.

Comment: Why do you want to disable it for INSERT?

Comment: My use case is to avoid those 2 unnecessary round trips to the db. It's not much but why not save a few milliseconds off of every request if it's possible.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How it works:

The persistence module define `create`: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/persistence.rb#L46

```
def create!(attributes = nil, &block)
  if attributes.is_a?(Array)
    attributes.collect { |attr| create!(attr, &block) }
  else
    object = new(attributes, &block)
    object.save!
    object
  end
end
```

It create an object and call `#save!`

It is not documented in the public api, but calls https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/transactions.rb#L290

```
def save!(*) #:nodoc:
  with_transaction_returning_status { super }
end
```

At this point the transaction wrap the save (super), which is at Persistence module again: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/persistence.rb#L141

```
def save!(*)
  create_or_update || raise(RecordNotSaved.new(nil, self))
end
```

Let's hack this with some new methods:

```
module ActiveRecord
  module Persistence
    module ClassMethods

      def atomic_create!(attributes = nil, &block)
        if attributes.is_a?(Array)
          raise "An array of records can't be atomic"
        else
          object = new(attributes, &block)
          object.atomic_save!
          object
        end
      end

    end

    alias_method :atomic_save!, :save!
  end
end

module ActiveRecord
  module Transactions

    def atomic_save!(*)
      super
    end

  end
end
```

Perhaps you want to use the standard `create!` method, then you need to redefine it. I define a first optional parameter `:atomic`, and when it's present means you want to use the `atomic_save!` method.

```
module ActiveRecord
  module Persistence
    module ClassMethods

      def create_with_atomic!(first = nil, second = nil, &block)
        attributes, atomic = second == nil ? [first, second] : [second, first]
        if attributes.is_a?(Array)
          create_without_atomic!(attributes, &block)
        else
          object = new(attributes, &block)
          atomic == :atomic ? object.atomic_save! : object.save!
          object
        end
      end
      alias_method_chain :create!, :atomic

    end
  end
end
```

With this in `config/initializers/<any_name>.rb` it can work.

**How it runs at console**:

```
~/rails/r41example (development) > Product.atomic_create!(name: 'atomic_create')
  SQL (99.4ms)  INSERT INTO "products" ("created_at", "name", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", "2015-03-22 03:50:07.558473"], ["name", "atomic_create"], ["updated_at", "2015-03-22 03:50:07.558473"]]
=> #<Product:0x000000083b1340> {
            :id => 1,
          :name => "atomic_create",
    :created_at => Sun, 22 Mar 2015 03:50:07 UTC +00:00,
    :updated_at => Sun, 22 Mar 2015 03:50:07 UTC +00:00
}
~/rails/r41example (development) > Product.create!(name: 'create with commit')
  (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.1ms)  INSERT INTO "products" ("created_at", "name", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", "2015-03-22 03:50:20.790566"], ["name", "create with commit"], ["updated_at", "2015-03-22 03:50:20.790566"]]
  (109.3ms)  commit transaction
=> #<Product:0x000000082f3138> {
            :id => 2,
          :name => "create with commit",
    :created_at => Sun, 22 Mar 2015 03:50:20 UTC +00:00,
    :updated_at => Sun, 22 Mar 2015 03:50:20 UTC +00:00
}
~/rails/r41example (development) > Product.create!(:atomic, name: 'create! atomic')
  SQL (137.3ms)  INSERT INTO "products" ("created_at", "name", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", "2015-03-22 03:51:03.001423"], ["name", "create! atomic"], ["updated_at", "2015-03-22 03:51:03.001423"]]
=> #<Product:0x000000082a0bb8> {
            :id => 3,
          :name => "create! atomic",
    :created_at => Sun, 22 Mar 2015 03:51:03 UTC +00:00,
    :updated_at => Sun, 22 Mar 2015 03:51:03 UTC +00:00
}
```

Caveat: You will lose after_rollback and after_commit callbacks!

Note: on 4.1 the methods create! and save! are in module Validations. On Rails 4.2 are in Persistence.

**Edit**: Perhaps you think you can earn the transaction elapsed time. In my examples the commit time goes to the inserts (I have a standard HD and I think you have an SSD).

Comment: That's a great explanation. From my point of view,  there is two reasons of removing transaction for insert/update queries: 1) it shouldn't be there, because it's unnecessary and 2) it speeds the entire system up. Yes, not so much, but if you're dealing with hundreds request per minute, it would be a nice bonus.
Anyway, it could be a potential PR to ActiveRecord

Comment: @Alexander thanks a lot! I take this as a learning challenge, but I don't think on a PR to AR, because I'll can't uphold it knowing the risk of lose transaction callbacks, and we have no benchmarks that show any improved speed.

Answer (score 5):

The problem here is that you want to modify behavior for a class-level method.  This is inherently not thread-safe, at the very least for concurrent transactions for other Stat objects.  A simple workaround would be to flag the instance as not requiring a transaction:

```
class Stat < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :skip_transaction

  def with_transaction_returning_status
    if skip_transaction
      yield
    else
      super
    end
  end
end

Stat.create! skip_transaction: true
```

If you are running on a single threaded framework, and therefore aren't concerned with suspending transactions for Stat objects during this time, you can use class level methods and wrap the call like so:

```
class Stat < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.transaction(*args)
    if @skip_transaction
      yield
    else
      super
    end
  end

  def self.skip_transaction
    begin
      @skip_transaction = true
      yield
    ensure
      @skip_transaction = nil
    end
  end
end

Stat.skip_transaction { Stat.create! }
```

Comment: Your first suggestion does not seem to have any effect on Rails 5

Comment: @akostadinov that's surprising, since the transaction mechanism doesn't appear to have changed much.  Do you have any code and SQL logs to demonstrate this?

Comment: I just copy/pasted your model code from above but used `Model.save skip_transaction: true`. Not create. I'm sure it was called because at first  I forgot `attr_accessor :skip_transaction` and it raised that no such local variabel or method exists.
My app is here but without the chenge https://github.com/akostadinov/ownthat/

Comment: Works fine on Rails 5.2. I replaced the body of `with_transaction_returning_status` with just `yield` to prevent a transaction (that specific table is not under transaction control and attempting a transaction will raise a SQL7008 (DB2 @ AS/400)) and it works as advertised.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to manually write your INSERT statement, still using ActiveRecord to execute it. This won't disable transactions for any other code you write.

```
sql = "INSERT INTO stats (created_at, updated_at) VALUES ('2015-03-16 11:20:08', '2015-03-16 11:20:08')"
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
```

Not as nice as using Alejandro's solution above, but does the trick - especially if it's a once off and the table is unlikely to change.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any nice way of doing this

On ruby 2.2 you can do

```
stat = Stat.new
stat.method(:save).super_method.call
```

This won't work pre ruby 2.2 (that's when `super_method` was added) and only works because in the list of ancestors, transactions is the first (or last depending on which way you order) to override save. If it wasn't then this code would skip over the 'wrong' save method. As such, I could hardly recommend this

You could do something like

```
stat = Stat.new
m = stat.method(:save)
until m.owner == ActiveRecord::Transactions
  m = m.super_method
end
m = m.super_method
```

To automatically walk up the chain until you have found the transactions bit, but there's no telling what code you might have skipped over.

Comment: Monkey-patching of `save` or other methods is not a solution. It can broke all ActiveRecord stack!

Comment: Indeed it can - which is why I said I wouldn't recommend it

Answer (score 0):

Answer of Alejandro Babio is extensive but wanted to explain why transaction is done in the first place.

[This answer](http://www.justinweiss.com/articles/a-couple-callback-gotchas-and-a-rails-5-fix/#comment-2490239731) explains what role does the transaction have in the call. Here is it in short:

```
begin transaction
insert record
after_save called
commit transaction
after_commit called
```

But provided no `after_save` hook is registered by developer, I wonder why transaction is not skipped. For high latency connections, the transaction may increase overall operation time 3 times :/ IMO Rails needs to be optimized.

Rails rejected such optimization, see why: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/26272