# Is it impossible to disable transactions in ActiveRecord? Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, transactions

I've inherited an import algorithm that uses ActiveRecord and it's super slow. Lots of people have reported such slowness in import scripts using ActiveRecord is due to its use of transactions.

I've removed as many transactions from the original script itself as possible, but it seems ActiveRecord is wrapping the whole request in an enormous transaction I can't get rid of.

I'm aware there are modules such as ar_import and techniques such as splitting the import into smaller chunks to work around this problem, but those solutions require huge changes to the import algorithm, and if I have to go that route, I'd rather just rewrite it in a language I know better anyway (like JavaScript).

It seems insane to me that I can't temporarily disable transactions in ActiveAdmin for doing some model changes. Does ActiveAdmin *depend* on transactions to work, or won't it let me disable them just because it's pathologically opinionated? And if I *can* temporarily disable them, how do I do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29075767/438992 and other hacks. Also, IIRC migrations run in a single transaction so there's some shenanigans there as well to turn them off for the duration. All that said--for massive DB operations it's often better to bypass AR and Rails altogether.