# Rails ActiveRecord: create without transaction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

Here is my code:

```
pry(main)> User.create!(password: 'password') 
(0.4ms)  BEGIN
User Create (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ...
(0.3ms)  COMMIT
```

How can I use  single `create!` without transaction?

Thanks all!

Comment: Sorry, not sure I understand, what do you mean by 'transaction'? Do you mean the executed 'insert' sql statement?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to skip transaction in ActiveRecord for INSERT ONLY statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29075767/how-to-skip-transaction-in-activerecord-for-insert-only-statement)

Comment: duplicated of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29075767/how-to-skip-transaction-in-activerecord-for-insert-only-statement